# Is stubbing/mocking necessary with 3rd party api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller, rspec2

I have an action in my controller that connects to a third party api and does some work. If the code succeeds then my user is saved. If the third party api fails, then the user is not saved.

```
def create
  if ThirdPartyApp.connect.eql? true
    User.create(params[:user])
  else
    redirect home_path
  end
end
```

I want to test the `User.create` code without having to worry about the third party app code. I'm aware of stubbing and mocking and understand the difference in that one tests instance methods and the other class methods. I'm unsure how to use this though in my rspec test as certain conditions can't be met in the test that are required for the third party app to work. Any help on how I can write this test with stubbing, mocking, or some other method would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few solutions here:

First, you could use a tool like VCR (Ryan Bates has a [great screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/291-testing-with-vcr) on this!) That way, you run the test the first time with the response from the API being recorded so that from the second time onwards it just 'replays' the 'recording' to use their terms.

Using stubbing/mocking on a request that is so dependant on an API response can be hard. If it were me (and I am guessing at how you are testing this controller action)

```
it "creates user" do
  ThirdPartyApp.any_instance.stub(:connect) { true }
  # fill in form or submit params as required
  User.count.should == 1 # or some other assertion
end
```

Then you can test the fail being:

```
it "fails from the api" do
  ThirdPartyApp.any_instance.stub(:connect) { false }
  # fill in form or submit params as required
  current_path.should == '/whatever' # or some other assertion
end
```

Others may argue a different solution, and if I had the choice in this circumstance I would go with VCR.

Comment: Hmm this project does have VCR I just haven't adopted it in my tests yet. Will look into it. Thanks. I'll give the answer in a day or two if no one comes up with a better answer.